# Retrieve the Current User name in sharepoint using webservices

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

I have designed a `infopath` form ,in that form load option I need to retrieve the current **USERNAME**. Who logged in the site must retrieve using `WebServices` only.
So I did that using `UserProfileServices.asmx` service and `GetProfileByName` Method.
But I'm getting different **USERNAMES** ,Sometimes my **USERNAME** Sometimes form Admin etc.....Please let me know how can I do this....

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what "sometimes" means...  And where did you get different Usernames from (WebService or from the InfoPath userName() function)?

If it's the function, this is default behavior if you fill out the form using the client (InfoPath Filler). If it's the WebService make sure you also append the domain to the userName() like this

```
concat("MyDomain\"; userName())
```